# AH01630: client denied by server configuration on the wsgi script

Tags: python-2.7, flask, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I am getting  "AH01630: client denied by server configuration" error on the wsgi script even after changing the access control to the one which suits to Apache 2.4 configuration and adding user/group (given the required permission to the files as well) to the WSGIDeomon process.

I am not sure what else can I do to resolve the same. The same error in the document root directory was resolved after changing the access control to "Require all granted" (as per Apache 2.4), but still exists for the wsgi scripts.

Configuration:

```
Apache/2.4.33 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.14
```

My httpd_conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName <DNSname of amazon ec2 service>

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/documents
    <Directory /usr/local/www/documents>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=ec2-user group=ec2-user threads=5 python-path=/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp/virt/lib64/python2.7
    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/www/wsg-scripts/myapp/myapp.wsgi
    <Directory /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    AllowOverride None
    Require method GET POST OPTIONS
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

myapp.wsgi:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/local/www/wsg-scripts/myapp/virt/lib64/python2.7/')

activate_this = '/usr/local/www/wsg-scripts/myapp/virt/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

from myapp import app as application
```

Error Log:

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 10063] [client 148.64.7.56:52323] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/local/www/wsg-scripts/myapp/myapp.wsgi
```

Webpage:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /myapp on this server.
```

Could you please help me to get the solution to this?

Comment: The user/group on ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` is not what is important for this error, what is, is that all the directories down to ``/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp`` are accessible to the Apache user.

Comment: BTW, don't use mod_wsgi 3.5. It is well over 5 years old and many more than 50 releases ago, and is not supported. Use a more up to date version.